# How java handles the results of bitwise operators

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

I trying to know to know how java finds the result is -ve or +ve for Bitwise operations?

```
int x=-5;
int y=8;
System.out.println(x&y); //8
System.out.println(x|y); //-5

x->1 0 1 1 (2's complement)
y->1 0 0 0 
x & y -> 1 0 0 0 ->8
x | y -> 1 0 1 1 ->-5(2's complement)
```

How java knows 1 0 1 1 is -5 ?

why doesn't it directly give o/p as 1 0 1 1's decimal equivalent 11 ?

Does it apply 2's complement on every result ?

I have seen the Assembly Code . It is IAND and IOR instructions.

Comment: check out here http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/bitwise-and-bitshift-operators-in-java-and-or-xor-left-right-shift-example-tutorial.html

Comment: He haven't explained anything related to -ve numbers..

Comment: on @AnandChoudhary link: `7) Integral types in Java (int, long, short and byte) are signed numbers in Java where most significant bit (MSB) represent sign of number. 1 will denote a negative number and 0 as MSB will denote a positive numbers`

Comment: The binary representation of -5 is `11111111111111111111111111111011` and not `1011`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the bitwise operators on 32-bit integers. So, the number "8" really has a lot of zeros in front, while "-5" has a lot of ones:

```
8  -> 0...01000
-5 -> 1...11011
```

So, Java does not need to "know" anything about the outcome or operands of the bitwiese operations. The "8" is a 32-bit number that starts with a 0, so it is positive. The "-5" is a 32-bit number that starts with a "1", so it is negative.

So, the answer to your question

> Does it apply 2's complement on every result ?

is: Yes, since all integers are signed number in Java, using 2's complement.